# How To Count Set of Text on a Web page

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a web page with a list of countries and I want to the count and output the total number of countries display on the page. How can i do this in Selenium c#

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post your code please?

Comment: please refer to [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) site for making a proper question for SO community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Url = ("https://gist.github.com/kalinchernev/486393efcca01623b18d");
    int contagem = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("blob-num")).Count();

    Console.WriteLine($"{contagem}");
```

Another solution:

You can also use `WebBrowser` from the `System.Net` library to do this, stay that way.

```
    private void GetCountries()
    {
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Navigate("https://gist.github.com/kalinchernev/486393efcca01623b18d");
        browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted);
    }


    int conta;  //number of countries
    public void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
        var links = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("tr");

        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
        {
            if (link.InnerHtml.Contains("blob-num"))
            {
                string countrie = link.InnerText;
                listbox.Items.Add($"{++conta} / {countrie}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't publish multiple answer for the same question. Rather club up all the contents and publish a single canonical answer.